# Rails Ajax - Javascript for DataTable is not working

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, datatable

I have a table where I want to delete entries via ajax. After the record is deleted the file `destroy.js.erb` will be executed and render the table via ajax in the DOM. This is working.

But not the complete file. After the `render partial` block the javascript is not working. So the `DataTable`and the `console.log` is not executed. *In the partial is no inline javascript.*

**destroy.js.erb**

```js
console.log("foo");
$("#tableWrapper").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'table' ) %>");
$("#table").DataTable();
console.log("foo2");
```

**Update**

OK, the `$("#table").DataTable();` cause the error. If I don't use this block the second `console.log` is working. But I have no error message.

Comment: Do you see any error in browser console?

Comment: @Gabbar Unfortunately not, that's my problem...

Comment: Is DataTable() something you introduce in the other javascript folder, via webpack?

Comment: @Gabbar no, I don't use Webpack. DataTable() comes from `gem 'jquery-datatables-rails'#, '~> 1.11.2'` and `//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables`